# How do I indicate to vegan function cca() that species data are presence/absence?

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to pass presence/absence species data and environmental data to `vegan::cca()`. I have not been able to determine if `cca()` interprets species values of 1 and 0 as presence/absence by default, or if I will need to formally indicate that values are presence/absence rather than abundance, or if there is a meaningful distinction between those two options in the context of data in this format at all.

Below is a dummy dataset in the format of my data, where 1=presence and 0=absence. All p/a data and values of environmental variables are entirely arbitrary.

```
library(vegan)

sites    <- c("site_a","site_b","site_c","site_d")

#four species, each present or absent in each of four plots
presabs_df <- data.frame(
  sp_w = c(1,0,1,1),
  sp_x = c(0,0,0,1),
  sp_y = c(0,1,0,1),
  sp_z = c(1,1,1,1))            

#three environmental variables, each recorded at each of four plots
environ_df <- data.frame(
  env_fact_i = c(12,14,16,19),
  env_fact_j = c(60,45,78,12),
  env_fact_k = c(2,5,1,3))      

rownames(presabs_df) <- sites
rownames(environ_df) <- sites

cca(presabs_df ~ env_fact_i + env_fact_j + env_fact_k, data = environ_df)
```

My question - how do I indicate to `cca()` that species data are presence/absence?

EDIT: I do not think that it is necessary to indicate formally that species data are p/a. When I replaced 1s with TRUE and 0s with FALSE (below) and passed that data frame to cca(), the results were identical to what was returned when data were 1s and 0s.

```
presabs_df <- data.frame(
  sp_w = c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE),
  sp_x = c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),
  sp_y = c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE),
  sp_z = c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE))
```

Comment: Yes, pretty sure that CCA will work fine with presence/absence and it doesn't need to be specified. Can't find a reference right now though

Comment: There is no need (and no way) to indicate that data are 1 or 0: they will just be handled like data of 1 and 0.